# Is saving the images with progressive property in Photoshop helping the images uploading in the browsers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I save images in Photoshop with progressive property, are these images progressively downloaded by the browsers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  That was the reason for the progressive property in the first place.  At one time browsers ran over 9600 bit / sec modems and it WAS important.

Comment: so, now it is completely useless ?

Comment: @Patrick: That depends on a lot of things.  A large image downloaded over a slow wireless connection might benefit.  And don't forget there still road-warriors out there using modems of the telephone line variety.  Personally I think the progressive download has little benefit.  I usually tune my website design to a minimum of at least DSL and just accept that some folks will find the site non-friendly if not downright unusable unless they turn images off.  It might be different if I was trying to meet federal or company requirements but for my personal site I don't bother.

Comment: It's not completely useless, but it's less important now. It allows people on slow connections to get a vague picture at the start that slowly increases in quality versus showing up line by line.